# How do I repeat "viewport movements" in vim?

Tags: vim

Say I just moved the "viewport" (is that the right word?) 10 lines down:

```
10<C-e>
```

Is there now a quick way I can repeat that viewport movement?

Comment: Some related viewport commands: `zz`, `zt`, and `zb`. See `:h scroll-cursor`.

Answer (score 2):

Using "." repeats the last edit only.

Only certain motions have repetition built in.
F, f, T, and t can be repeated or reversed with ; and , (semi-colon and comma).

Searching with / can of course be repeated with n and N.

To repeat more complex motions you could use the [repmo](https://github.com/vim-scripts/repmo.vim) plugin.

<C-e> scrolls the edit window.

With repeat motion installed:

Typing ";" will repeat the last motion command eg. 10<C-e>